# Leaked Handles in Test after Migration to Jest 26

Tags: testing, npm, jestjs, nestjs

I have a NestJS app running tests in jest. The test were fine before, but since moving migrating to jest version 26, I have issues with opn handles after the test is complete.

In jest version 25, I was able to set up and test down my tests like this:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
const moduleFixture = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [AssignmentsModule, TimeSheetsModule, ExpensesModule, SessionModule]
})
.compile();

assignmentService = moduleFixture.get<AssignmentsService>(AssignmentsService);
assignmentsController = moduleFixture.get<AssignmentsController>(AssignmentsController);
app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
await app.init();
server = await app.getHttpServer();

serverRequest = await request(server);
authorizationHeaders = await getAuthorizationHeaders(serverRequest);
```

});

---

```
afterAll(async () => {
    await serverRequest.end();
    await server.close();
    await app.close();
  });
```

After migrating, `await serverRequset.end()` returns an error (the function is no longer available)

I am able to produce some logging by using `require('leaked-handles')`. Here is a sample of that:

---

```
http server handle leaked at one of: 
    at ExpressAdapter.initHttpServer (/Users/princetone/Projects/TOLv4/tes-timeonline-api/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/adapters/express-adapter.js:144:36)
http server handle { fd: 16, address: { address: '::', family: 'IPv6', port: 50272 } }

http handle leaked at one of: 
    at Test.Object.<anonymous>.Request.request (/Users/princetone/Projects/TOLv4/tes-timeonline-api/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:622:31)
http stream {
  fd: 18,
  readable: true,
  writable: true,
  address: { address: '127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv4', port: 50273 },
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/time-sheets/ML4W3K',
  host: '127.0.0.1:50272'
}

http stream {
  fd: 17,
  readable: true,
  writable: true,
  address: { address: '::ffff:127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv6', port: 50272 },
  method: undefined,
  path: undefined,
  host: undefined
}
```

I am running:
node v14
npm v6
jest v26
@nestjs/core, @nestjs/common @nestjs/testing v9.4.3

I've spend a lot of time searching around for an answer. Could anyone help to point out what changes in jest 26 may be leading to this issue?